# Python Camelot - export files without the additional string appended to the filename

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-camelot

Python 3.7 with Camelot 0.7.3.  Currently, Camelot exports the converted file with 'page-*-table-*' appended to the file name - we have very specific file name requirements for our application, and I'm trying to export the file without that extra string appended to the file name.  Is this possible?  The documentation does not mention anything about how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

> The documentation does not mention anything about how to get around this.

I'm not sure what you mean. https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/ says:

> Here’s how you can extract tables from PDF files. Check out the PDF
>   used in this example here.
>
> ```
> >>> import camelot
> >>> tables = camelot.read_pdf('foo.pdf')
> >>> tables <TableList n=1>
> >>> tables.export('foo.csv', f='csv', compress=True) # json, excel, html
> ```

Using `tables.export` exports all the tables in the PDF to separate files and needs to distinguish them by the filenames.

If you only need to export a specific table, use the example further down on the page:

> ```
> >>> tables[0].to_csv('foo.csv') # to_json, to_excel, to_html
> ```

This passes the filename unchanged to `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`, as can be seen in https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/blob/master/camelot/core.py#L571.

Comment: Yes I am doing exactly that.  If the `foo.pdf` file is one page and has one table, the above code (without `compress=true` since a zip file will not work for us) generates a file called foo-page1-table1.csv.